# Counting unique words

Tags: python

**Question:**

Devise an algorithm and write the Python code to count the number of unique words in a given passage.

The paragraph may contain words with special characters such as `!`, `?`, `.`, `,` , `:` and `;` and digits are not permitted.

Special character must occur only at the end of a word in a passage that is `Hello World!` is valid but `Hello !World` or `Hello Wor!ld` is invalid.

No two special character occur together. Print `Invalid input` for such cases.

Count words without special characters. Counting must case insensitive. Print words in lower case and in sorted order.

**My code:**

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint`
import re
line=raw_input()
line.lower()
l=line.split(" ")
d=set(l)
count={}
for word in d:
    if word in count:
        count[word]+=1
    else:
        count[word]=1
pprint(count)
```

Expected Output:

```
{'are': 2, 'better': 1, 'dear': 2, 'how': 1, 'you': 2}
```

My Program Output:

```
{'Are': 1, 'How': 1, 'are': 1, 'better': 1, 'dear?': 1, 'you': 1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove these 2 lines and add the line:

```
REMOVE:  
line.lower()   
l=line.split(" ")

ADD:
l = re.sub(r"\s+[\!\?\.\,\:\@]+\s+", r" ", s2.lower()).split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is wrong iterating. Since `set()` returns unordered unique collection, you are iterating through unique list.

Instead of `for word in d:` try: `for word in l:`

edit:
And change `if word in count:` into `if word in count.keys():`, because you want to check if key `word` exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you didn't convert your input to lower case because the `str.lower` doesn't works in-place.So you need to change the following line :

```
line.lower()
```

to :

```
line = line.lower()
```

But as a more pythonic way you can split your sentence to get a list of words and strip them with punctuation then use `collections.Counter` to get a dictionary contains the words and those frequency.

```
from collections import Counter

line=raw_input().lower()

counter_object= Counter([i.strip('!?.,:;') for i in line.split()])
```