# How do I create an inverted index containing information on the number of occurrences of each word in each document

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, information-extraction

I have a dataset containing 250 data points of text information. Now I need to create an inverted index containing information on the occurrences of each word within each key. I have around 250 keys and a list of the preprocessed collection of words.

I have tried playing around with Whoosh libraries but with little success. The documentation seems a little vague on how it works. I receive Unknown Field Error.

```
from whoosh.fields import Schema, TEXT, KEYWORD, ID, STORED
from whoosh.analysis import StemmingAnalyzer
schema = Schema(Title = ID(stored = True), Content = `enter code here`KEYWORD(stored = True))
import os, os.path
from whoosh import index
if not os.path.exists('inv_indexdir'):
    os.mkdir('inv_indexdir')
ix = index.create_in('inv_indexdir', schema)
import whoosh.index as index
ix = index.open_dir('inv_indexdir')
writer = ix.writer()
writer.add_document(title = u'Title', content = u'Content', path = u'json_data.json')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting unique words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296897/counting-unique-words)

Comment: You should have a look on [SKLEARN-Text feature extraction](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction)

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not clear. Please add more context about your overall goal.